# web audio api wont play sound

Tags: javascript, audio, web

pls guys im stock i need help with these i keep getting errors,bufferlist undefined,loadDogSound undefined.if dont get any error it doesnt play.

Thank you in advance.

```js
<script>
window.onload = init;
var context;
var bufferLoader;

function init() {
  // Fix up prefixing
  window.AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;
  context = new AudioContext();

  bufferLoader = new BufferLoader(
    context,
    [
      'audio/b.mp3',
      'audio/a.mp3',
    ],
    finishedLoading
    );

  bufferLoader.load();
}

function finishedLoading(bufferList) {
 context = new AudioContext();
  // Create two sources and play them both together.
  var source1 = context.createBufferSource();
  var source2 = context.createBufferSource();
  source1.buffer = bufferList[0];
  source2.buffer = bufferList[1];

  source1.connect(context.destination);
  source2.connect(context.destination);
  source1.start(0);
  source2.start(0);
}

</script>
```

Comment: What browser are you using? Not long ago it was very experimental and you have to turn it on in chrome. Today is supposed to work in almost all the popular browsers. Check here: http://caniuse.com/#search=AudioContext

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to make a script that references an object discussed on this page: http://middleearmedia.com/web-audio-api-bufferloader/

According to the instructions you should have created a file called buffer-loader.js and put the following line in the head of your html file:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="buffer-loader.js"></script>
```

Here is a pastie to the file you are missing for your convenience: http://pastie.org/10227922

When I add this file, your example works without error.

Comment: actually i didnt get it from the link you gave but thanks. i goy it from [link](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webaudio/intro/)